# Error parsing a char (――) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm writing a parser to parse huge chunks of English text using attoparsec. Everything has been great so far, except for parsing this char `"――"`. I know it is just 2 dashes together `"--"`. The weird thing is, the parser catches it in this code:

```
wordSeparator :: Parser ()
wordSeparator = many1 (space <|> satisfy (inClass "――?!,:")) >> pure ()
```

but not in this case:

```
specialChars = ['――', '?', '!', ',', ':']
wordSeparator :: Parser ()
wordSeparator = many1 (space <|> satisfy (inClass specialChars)) >> pure ()
```

The reason I'm using the list `specialChars` is because I have a lot of characters to consider and I apply it multiple cases. And for the input consider: `"I am ――Walt Whitman._"` and the output is supposed to be `{"I", "am", "Walt", "Whiteman."}` I believe it's mostly because `"――"` is not a Char? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Char` is one character, full stop. `――` is two characters, so it is two `Char`s. You can fit as many `Char`s as you want into a `String`, but you certainly cannot fit two `Char`s into one `Char`.

Since `satisfy` considers individual characters at a time, it probably isn’t what you want if you need to parse a sequence of two characters as a single unit. The `inClass` function just produces a predicate on characters (`inClass` partially applied to one argument produces a function of type `Char -> Bool`), so `inClass "――"` is the same as `inClass ['―', '―']`, which is just the same as `inClass ['―']` since duplicates are irrelevant. That won’t help you much.

Consider using `string` instead of or in combination with `inClass`, since it is designed to handle *sequences* of characters. For example, something like this might better suit your needs:

```
wordSeparator :: Parser ()
wordSeparator = many1 (space <|> string "――" <|> satisfy (inClass "?!,:")) >> pure ()
```

Comment: Sorry I should have indicated that I have been using Data.Text and using string "--" would cause an error. But however, I fixed it by using another inClass. You can see my updated post.

Comment: @ceeks [`string` from `Data.Attoparsec.Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:string) will work just fine with `Data.Text`. You may need to use `OverloadedStrings` or `Data.Text.pack` to produce a `Text` value for the argument to `Data.Attoparsec.Text.string`, but believe me, it really is the function you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I will do so. But just out of sheer curiosity, what kind of implications/consequences would it have if I used another satisfy (inclass "--") ?

Comment: @ceeks As I mentioned in my answer, `inClass "――"` would be precisely equivalent to `inClass ['―']`, so your parser would treat the string `――` as two distinct separators, and it would parse a single `―` as a separator. I assume this isn’t what you want, since if it was, you would just write `inClass "―"` and be done with it.